# UPDATE from another table using LIKE between target and source columns to match rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update, sql-like

I have 2 tables, `tblSource` and `tblTarget`

**tblSource**:

| ID | Info | Born | City |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1954 Barry Nelson TV series | US | San Francisco |
| 2 | 1954 Sean Connery Dr. No | UK | Edinburgh |
| 3 | 1967 David Niven Casino Royale | UK | London |
| 4 | 1967 George Lazenby On Her Majesty´s Secret Service | AU | New South Wales |
| 5 | 1969 Roger Moore Moonraker | UK | London |
| 6 | 1973 Timothy Dalton The Living Daylights | UK | Wales |
| 7 | 1987 Pierce Brosnan The World Is Not Enough | IE | County Louth |

**tblTarget**:

| ID | Name | Born | City |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | Sean Connery |  |  |
| 11 | Roger Moore |  |  |
| 12 | Timothy Dalton |  |  |
| 13 | Pierce Brosnan |  |  |
| 14 | Daniel Craig |  |  |

Goal is to update `Born` and `City` columns in `tblTarget` by matching rows with LIKE from `tblSource`. On a row without a match, update must not happen.
Tables are not huge so a hardcoded list like below can be created from `tblTarget` and used in SQL:

```
('%Sean Connery%',
 '%Roger Moore%',
 '%Timothy Dalton%',
 '%Pierce Brosnan%',
 '%Daniel Craig%')
```

Sure, a fully dynamic solution would be ideal for future needs

The result should be,

**tblTarget**:

| ID | Name | Born | City |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | Sean Connery | UK | Edinburgh |
| 11 | Roger Moore | UK | London |
| 12 | Timothy Dalton | UK | Wales |
| 13 | Pierce Brosnan | IE | County Louth |
| 14 | Daniel Craig |  |  |

I'm this far but don't know how to write LIKE condition properly

```
UPDATE t
SET t.Born = s.Born,
    t.City = s.City
FROM tblTarget t
JOIN tblSource s
ON t.Name LIKE s.Info
WHERE s.Info IN 
('%Sean Connery%',
 '%Roger Moore%',
 '%Timothy Dalton%',
 '%Pierce Brosnan%',
 '%Daniel Craig%')
```

Any help highly appreciated

Comment: are you using azure sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having the same data duplicated in multiple tables is probably a design flaw, however you can join using a *like* match.

On the assumption your source data does not contain duplicates you can simply join the tables and use an updatable table expression;

```
with updateme as (
    select t.*, s.born sBorn, s.City sCity
    from target t
    join source s on s.info like Concat('%', t.name, '%')
)
update updateme set born = SBorn, city = sCity;
```

if your source table contains multiple rows per *Name* you could move the join to a *cross apply* and select 1 row only - again presumably your source table would be duplicating the same data per *Name*.

```
with updateme as (
    select t.*, s.sBorn, s.sCity
    from target t
    cross apply (
        select top(1) s.born sBorn, s.City sCity
        from source s where s.info like Concat('%', t.name, '%')
    )s
)
update updateme set born = SBorn, city = sCity;
```

Comment: Data comes from 2 different systems, thus duplicates.

Source has only unique values so your first solution is suitable in this case. Works perfectly!

Did not test your second solution yet but I trust it works too. I might need in future a  version which picks value from a row with biggest datetime value but for now this is good. Thanks Stu!